# Read and process all files from a List

Tags: python, json, list

the sample script below able to read file from fileDir and add the files onto a list(fileList). I can execute the function and insert data to db. The issue now this just work for only single json file...if got more files in fileDir the script will only execute one file... If you notice I use the same dataFile variable name till end of the process of data insertion.

I would like to have the capability to open and read more files one by one. Please show and help me the right way to resolve it. Thank you

logFile

```
1.json
2.json
```

print(listFile) output

```
[{'1': 'one'}, {'2': 'two'}]
```

```
##Open and read file
fileDir = 'logFile/*.json'
listFile = []
for file1 in glob.iglob(fileDir):
    with open(file1,'r') as f:
        dataFile = json.load(f)
        listFile.append(dataFile)
#print(listFile)

##function to read dataFile and insert data file to db
def db(db_name, table_name):
    with open(file1,'r') as f:
        dataFile = json.load(f)

    ##Process raw dataFiles and extract data
    for entry in dataFile:
        some processing to extract and append data

    ##Insert clean dataFile onto db
    sql = "INSERT INTO ....."
    cursor.executemany( sql, dataFile ....)
    db.commit()
    db.close()
```

---

**I'm thinking if all files is in a list [ ]. Is it possible to open and read file one by one from a list?**

```
fileDir = 'logFile'
file_list = os.listdir(fileDir)

for jf in file_list:
    #print(jf)
```

print(jf) output

```
['1.json', '2.json']
```

try to open and read each json file in the list

```
with open(jf, 'r') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
        print(data)
```

got error

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '1.json'
```

Any help appreciate. Thanks

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: The script work for single json file... thus if i have multiple json file in directory only one file can be process and insert to db.

Comment: You are using for loop to iterate directory and adding file names to list, WhereAs in db function you are just calling file1, you need to add same for loop in the db function as well

Comment: can you show me some example ...not sure how to get for loop in the function....thanks

Answer (score 1):

The function is fine to put any number of file to add in database, But problem is you are just providing only 1 file to it.

So if you add an additional for loop into `db` function it should work.

```
##Open and read file
fileDir = 'logFile/*.json'
listFile = []
for file1 in glob.iglob(fileDir):
    with open(file1,'r') as f:
        dataFile = json.load(f)
        listFile.append(dataFile)
#print(listFile)

##function to read dataFile and insert data file to db
def db(db_name, table_name):
    dataFile = ""
    for file1 in glob.iglob(fileDir): 
        with open(file1,'r') as f:
            dataFile = json.load(f)

        ##Process raw dataFiles and extract data
        for entry in dataFile:
            some processing to extract and append data

        ##Insert clean dataFile onto db
        sql = "INSERT INTO ....."
        cursor.executemany( sql, dataFile ....)

    db.commit()
    db.close()
```

You can move commit statement inside loop, if you feel I am expert of SQL.

Comment: No need to have list (listFile = [])? sorry I don't understand dataFile = " "...

Comment: I just edited code to use list you populated "fileList", Now this should work fine, I added `dataFile=""` to make scope of this variable outside of with block also.

Comment: for file1 in listFile: ---> listFile here is a list...open(file1, 'r') this got error 'TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not dict'...

Comment: Edited, i was thinking that your files are at same location, try updated code

Comment: Hi sir...thanks for your input and comments. As for now it doesnt work but it does give me the idea...thank you.

Comment: Another idea is to read each files from a list, can we open and read file one by one from a list? Updated above.